# Conda cannot update - CondaHttpError

Tags: python, anaconda

I've been trying to update my conda with the command line

*conda update --all -y*

but its returning an HttpError. I've tried several times even with fast internet but it still returns the following error.

(C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root) C:\Users\User1>conda update --all -y
Fetching package metadata ...............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\my_root:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
attrs:                              17.4.0-py_0                conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache:      1.4-py36_1                 conda-forge
blinker:                            1.4-py_0                   conda-forge
boto3:                              1.5.24-py_0                conda-forge
botocore:                           1.8.38-py_0                conda-forge
bz2file:                            0.98-py36_0
gensim:                             3.3.0-py36_vc14_0          conda-forge [vc14]
jmespath:                           0.9.3-py36_0               conda-forge
krb5:                               1.14.2-vc14_0              conda-forge [vc14]
oauthlib:                           2.0.6-py_0                 conda-forge
parso:                              0.1.1-py_0                 conda-forge
pluggy:                             0.6.0-py_0                 conda-forge
pyjwt:                              1.5.3-py_0                 conda-forge
python-crfsuite:                    0.9.2-py36_vc14_0          conda-forge [vc14]
pywinpty:                           0.5-py36_1                 conda-forge
requests-oauthlib:                  0.8.0-py36_1               conda-forge
s3transfer:                         0.1.12-py36_0              conda-forge
send2trash:                         1.4.2-py_0                 conda-forge
smart_open:                         1.5.6-py36_1               conda-forge
terminado:                          0.8.1-py36_0               conda-forge
twython:                            3.6.0-py36_0               conda-forge
winpty:                             0.4.3-vc14_2               conda-forge [vc14]
```

The following packages will be UPDATED:

```
alabaster:                          0.7.10-py36hcd07829_0                  --> 0.7.10-py36_1              conda-forge
anaconda:                           5.0.1-py36h8316230_2                   --> custom-py36h363777c_0
anaconda-navigator:                 1.6.9-py36hc720852_0                   --> 1.6.12-py36hdad2993_0
anaconda-project:                   0.8.0-py36h8b3bf89_0                   --> 0.8.2-py36_0               conda-forge
astropy:                            2.0.2-py36h06391c4_4                   --> 2.0.4-py36_0               conda-forge
babel:                              2.5.0-py36h35444c1_0                   --> 2.5.1-py36_0               conda-forge
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size: 1.0.0-py36h79ab834_2                   --> 1.0.0-py_3                 conda-forge
bleach:                             2.0.0-py36h0a7e3d6_0                   --> 2.0.0-py_1                 conda-forge
bokeh:                              0.12.10-py36h0be3b39_0                 --> 0.12.13-py36_0             conda-forge
bottleneck:                         1.2.1-py36hd119dfa_0                   --> 1.2.1-py36_1               conda-forge
ca-certificates:                    2017.08.26-h94faf87_0                  --> 2017.11.5-0                conda-forge
certifi:                            2017.7.27.1-py36h043bc9e_0             --> 2017.11.5-py36_0           conda-forge
cffi:                               1.10.0-py36hae3d1b5_1                  --> 1.11.2-py36_0              conda-forge
click:                              6.7-py36hec8c647_0                     --> 6.7-py_1                   conda-forge
cloudpickle:                        0.4.0-py36h639d8dc_0                   --> 0.5.2-py_0                 conda-forge
comtypes:                           1.1.2-py36heb9b3d1_0                   --> 1.1.3-py36_0               conda-forge
cryptography:                       2.0.3-py36h123decb_1                   --> 2.1.4-py36_0               conda-forge
cython:                             0.26.1-py36h18049ac_0                  --> 0.27.3-py36_0              conda-forge
dask:                               0.15.3-py36h396fcb9_0                  --> 0.16.1-py_0                conda-forge
dask-core:                          0.15.3-py36hd651449_0                  --> 0.16.1-py_0                conda-forge
distributed:                        1.19.1-py36h8504682_0                  --> 1.20.2-py36_0              conda-forge
freetype:                           2.8-vc14h17c9bdf_0                     --> 2.8.1-vc14_0               conda-forge [vc14]
h5py:                               2.7.0-py36hfbe0a52_1                   --> 2.7.1-py36_2               conda-forge
hdf5:                               1.10.1-vc14hb361328_0                  --> 1.10.1-vc14_1              conda-forge [vc14]
html5lib:                           0.999999999-py36ha09b1f3_0             --> 1.0.1-py_0                 conda-forge
intel-openmp:                       2018.0.0-hcd89f80_7                    --> 2018.0.0-hd92c6cd_8
ipykernel:                          4.6.1-py36hbb77b34_0                   --> 4.8.1-py36_0               conda-forge
ipython:                            6.1.0-py36h236ecc8_1                   --> 6.2.1-py36_1               conda-forge
ipywidgets:                         7.0.0-py36h2e74ada_0                   --> 7.1.1-py36_0               conda-forge
itsdangerous:                       0.24-py36hb6c5a24_1                    --> 0.24-py_2                  conda-forge
jedi:                               0.10.2-py36hed927a0_0                  --> 0.11.1-py36_0              conda-forge
jinja2:                             2.9.6-py36h10aa3a0_1                   --> 2.10-py36_0                conda-forge
jpeg:                               9b-vc14h4d7706e_1                      --> 9b-vc14_2                  conda-forge [vc14]
jsonschema:                         2.6.0-py36h7636477_0                   --> 2.6.0-py36_1               conda-forge
jupyter_client:                     5.1.0-py36h9902a9a_0                   --> 5.2.2-py36_0               conda-forge
jupyter_core:                       4.3.0-py36h511e818_0                   --> 4.4.0-py_0                 conda-forge
jupyterlab:                         0.27.0-py36h34cc53b_2                  --> 0.31.5-py36_1              conda-forge
jupyterlab_launcher:                0.4.0-py36h22c3ccf_0                   --> 0.10.3-py36_0              conda-forge
libpng:                             1.6.32-vc14h5163883_3                  --> 1.6.34-vc14_0              conda-forge [vc14]
libtiff:                            4.0.8-vc14h04e2a1e_10                  --> 4.0.9-vc14_0               conda-forge [vc14]
libxml2:                            2.9.4-vc14h8fd0f11_5                   --> 2.9.5-vc14_1               conda-forge [vc14]
libxslt:                            1.1.29-vc14hf85b8d4_5                  --> 1.1.32-vc14_0              conda-forge [vc14]
llvmlite:                           0.20.0-py36_0                          --> 0.21.0-py36_0              conda-forge
lxml:                               4.1.0-py36h0dcd83c_0                   --> 4.1.1-py36_0               conda-forge
matplotlib:                         2.1.0-py36h11b4b9c_0                   --> 2.1.2-py36_0               conda-forge
mistune:                            0.7.4-py36h4874169_0                   --> 0.8.3-py_0                 conda-forge
mkl:                                2018.0.0-h36b65af_4                    --> 2018.0.1-h2108138_4
mpmath:                             0.19-py36he326802_2                    --> 1.0.0-py_0                 conda-forge
msgpack-python:                     0.4.8-py36h58b1e9d_0                   --> 0.5.1-py36_0               conda-forge
nbconvert:                          5.3.1-py36h8dc0fde_0                   --> 5.3.1-py_1                 conda-forge
networkx:                           2.0-py36hff991e3_0                     --> 2.0-py36_1                 conda-forge
nltk:                               3.2.4-py36hd0e0a39_0                   --> 3.2.5-py_0                 conda-forge
notebook:                           5.0.0-py36hd9fbf6f_2                   --> 5.4.0-py36_0               conda-forge
numba:                              0.35.0-np113py36_10                    --> 0.36.2-np114py36h12cb543_0
numexpr:                            2.6.2-py36h7ca04dc_1                   --> 2.6.4-py36_0               conda-forge
numpy:                              1.13.3-py36ha320f96_0                  --> 1.14.0-py36h4a99626_1
openpyxl:                           2.4.8-py36hf3b77f6_1                   --> 2.5.0-py36_0               conda-forge
openssl:                            1.0.2l-vc14hcac20b0_2                  --> 1.0.2n-vc14_0              conda-forge [vc14]
pandas:                             0.20.3-py36hce827b7_2                  --> 0.22.0-py36_0              conda-forge
pandoc:                             1.19.2.1-hb2460c7_1                    --> 2.1.1-0                    conda-forge
patsy:                              0.4.1-py36h42cefec_0                   --> 0.5.0-py36_0               conda-forge
pep8:                               1.7.0-py36h0f3d67a_0                   --> 1.7.1-py_0                 conda-forge
pillow:                             4.2.1-py36hdb25ab2_0                   --> 5.0.0-py36_0               conda-forge
py:                                 1.4.34-py36ha4aca3a_1                  --> 1.5.2-py_0                 conda-forge
pycosat:                            0.6.2-py36hf17546d_1                   --> 0.6.3-py36_0               conda-forge
pycurl:                             7.43.0-py36h086bf4c_3                  --> 7.43.0.1-py36h74b6da3_0
pylint:                             1.7.4-py36ha4e6ded_0                   --> 1.8.1-py36_0               conda-forge
pysocks:                            1.6.7-py36h698d350_1                   --> 1.6.8-py36_1               conda-forge
pytables:                           3.4.2-py36h71138e3_2                   --> 3.4.2-py36_7               conda-forge
pytest:                             3.2.1-py36h753b05e_1                   --> 3.4.0-py36_0               conda-forge
python:                             3.6.3-h9e2ca53_1                       --> 3.6.4-0                    conda-forge
pytz:                               2017.2-py36h05d413f_1                  --> 2017.3-py_2                conda-forge
pywavelets:                         0.5.2-py36hc649158_0                   --> 0.5.2-py36_1               conda-forge
pyzmq:                              16.0.2-py36h38c27d9_2                  --> 16.0.2-py36_3              conda-forge
rope:                               0.10.5-py36hcaf5641_0                  --> 0.10.7-py36_0              conda-forge
scikit-image:                       0.13.0-py36h6dffa3f_1                  --> 0.13.1-py36_0              conda-forge
scipy:                              0.19.1-py36h7565378_3                  --> 1.0.0-py36h1260518_0
seaborn:                            0.8.0-py36h62cb67c_0                   --> 0.8.1-py36_0               conda-forge
setuptools:                         36.5.0-py36h65f9e6e_0                  --> 38.4.0-py36_0              conda-forge
sphinx:                             1.6.3-py36h9bb690b_0                   --> 1.6.7-py36_0               conda-forge
spyder:                             3.2.4-py36h8845eaa_0                   --> 3.2.6-py36_0               conda-forge
sqlalchemy:                         1.1.13-py36h5948d12_0                  --> 1.2.1-py36_0               conda-forge
sqlite:                             3.20.1-vc14h7ce8c62_1                  --> 3.20.1-vc14_2              conda-forge [vc14]
toolz:                              0.8.2-py36he152a52_0                   --> 0.8.2-py_2                 conda-forge
tornado:                            4.5.2-py36h57f6048_0                   --> 4.5.3-py36_0               conda-forge
vs2015_runtime:                     14.0.25123-hd4c4e62_2                  --> 14.0.25420-0               conda-forge
werkzeug:                           0.12.2-py36h866a736_0                  --> 0.14.1-py_0                conda-forge
wheel:                              0.29.0-py36h6ce6cde_1                  --> 0.30.0-py36_2              conda-forge
widgetsnbextension:                 3.0.2-py36h364476f_1                   --> 3.1.3-py36_0               conda-forge
xlrd:                               1.1.0-py36h1cb58dc_1                   --> 1.1.0-py_2                 conda-forge
xlwings:                            0.11.4-py36hd3cf94d_0                  --> 0.11.7-py36_0              conda-forge
```

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

```
anaconda-client:                    1.6.5-py36hd36550c_0                   --> 1.6.5-py_0                 conda-forge
asn1crypto:                         0.22.0-py36h8e79faa_1                  --> 0.22.0-py36_0              conda-forge
astroid:                            1.5.3-py36h9d85297_0                   --> 1.5.3-py36_0               conda-forge
backports:                          1.0-py36h81696a8_1                     --> 1.0-py36_1                 conda-forge
beautifulsoup4:                     4.6.0-py36hd4cc5e8_1                   --> 4.6.0-py36_0               conda-forge
bitarray:                           0.8.1-py36h6af124b_0                   --> 0.8.1-py36_0               conda-forge
bkcharts:                           0.2-py36h7e685f7_0                     --> 0.2-py36_0                 conda-forge
blaze:                              0.11.3-py36h8a29ca5_0                  --> 0.11.3-py36_0              conda-forge
bzip2:                              1.0.6-vc14hdec8e7a_1                   --> 1.0.6-vc14_1               conda-forge [vc14]
chardet:                            3.0.4-py36h420ce6e_1                   --> 3.0.4-py36_0               conda-forge
clyent:                             1.2.2-py36hb10d595_1                   --> 1.2.2-py36_0               conda-forge
colorama:                           0.3.9-py36h029ae33_0                   --> 0.3.9-py36_0               conda-forge
conda-verify:                       2.0.0-py36h065de53_0                   --> 2.0.0-py36_0               conda-forge
contextlib2:                        0.5.5-py36he5d52c0_0                   --> 0.5.5-py36_0               conda-forge
curl:                               7.55.1-vc14hdaba4a4_3                  --> 7.55.1-vc14_0              conda-forge [vc14]
cycler:                             0.10.0-py36h009560c_0                  --> 0.10.0-py36_0              conda-forge
cytoolz:                            0.8.2-py36h547e66e_0                   --> 0.8.2-py36_0               conda-forge
datashape:                          0.5.4-py36h5770b85_0                   --> 0.5.4-py36_0               conda-forge
decorator:                          4.1.2-py36he63a57b_0                   --> 4.1.2-py36_0               conda-forge
docutils:                           0.14-py36h6012d8f_0                    --> 0.14-py36_0                conda-forge
entrypoints:                        0.2.3-py36hfd66bb0_2                   --> 0.2.3-py36_1               conda-forge
et_xmlfile:                         1.0.1-py36h3d2d736_0                   --> 1.0.1-py36_0               conda-forge
fastcache:                          1.0.2-py36hffdae1b_0                   --> 1.0.2-py36_0               conda-forge
filelock:                           2.0.12-py36hd7ddd41_0                  --> 2.0.6-py36_0               conda-forge
flask:                              0.12.2-py36h98b5e8f_0                  --> 0.12.2-py36_0              conda-forge
flask-cors:                         3.0.3-py36h8a3855d_0                   --> 3.0.3-py36_0               conda-forge
gevent:                             1.2.2-py36h342a76c_0                   --> 1.2.2-py36_0               conda-forge
glob2:                              0.5-py36h11cc1bd_1                     --> 0.5-py36_0                 conda-forge
greenlet:                           0.4.12-py36ha00ad21_0                  --> 0.4.12-py36_0              conda-forge
heapdict:                           1.0.0-py36h21fa5f4_0                   --> 1.0.0-py36_0               conda-forge
icu:                                58.2-vc14hc45fdbb_0                    --> 58.2-vc14_0                conda-forge [vc14]
idna:                               2.6-py36h148d497_1                     --> 2.6-py36_1                 conda-forge
imageio:                            2.2.0-py36had6c2d2_0                   --> 2.2.0-py36_0               conda-forge
imagesize:                          0.7.1-py36he29f638_0                   --> 0.7.1-py36_0               conda-forge
ipython_genutils:                   0.2.0-py36h3c5d0ee_0                   --> 0.2.0-py36_0               conda-forge
isort:                              4.2.15-py36h6198cc5_0                  --> 4.2.15-py36_0              conda-forge
jdcal:                              1.3-py36h64a5255_0                     --> 1.3-py36_0                 conda-forge
jupyter:                            1.0.0-py36h422fd7e_2                   --> 1.0.0-py36_0               conda-forge
jupyter_console:                    5.2.0-py36h6d89b47_1                   --> 5.2.0-py36_0               conda-forge
lazy-object-proxy:                  1.3.1-py36hd1c21d2_0                   --> 1.3.1-py36_0               conda-forge
libiconv:                           1.15-vc14h29686d3_5                    --> 1.14-vc14_4                conda-forge [vc14]
libssh2:                            1.8.0-vc14hcf584a9_2                   --> 1.8.0-vc14_2               conda-forge [vc14]
locket:                             0.2.0-py36hfed976d_1                   --> 0.2.0-py36_1               conda-forge
lockfile:                           0.12.2-py36h0468280_0                  --> 0.12.2-py36_0              conda-forge
lzo:                                2.10-vc14h0a64fa6_1                    --> 2.10-vc14_0                conda-forge [vc14]
markupsafe:                         1.0-py36h0e26971_1                     --> 1.0-py36_0                 conda-forge
mccabe:                             0.6.1-py36hb41005a_1                   --> 0.6.1-py36_0               conda-forge
menuinst:                           1.4.10-py36h42196fb_0                  --> 1.4.8-py36_0               conda-forge
multipledispatch:                   0.4.9-py36he44c36e_0                   --> 0.4.9-py36_0               conda-forge
nbformat:                           4.4.0-py36h3a5bc1b_0                   --> 4.4.0-py36_0               conda-forge
nose:                               1.3.7-py36h1c3779e_2                   --> 1.3.7-py36_2               conda-forge
numpydoc:                           0.7.0-py36ha25429e_0                   --> 0.7.0-py36_0               conda-forge
odo:                                0.5.1-py36h7560279_0                   --> 0.5.1-py36_0               conda-forge
olefile:                            0.44-py36h0a7bdd2_0                    --> 0.44-py36_0                conda-forge
packaging:                          16.8-py36ha0986f6_1                    --> 16.8-py36_0                conda-forge
pandocfilters:                      1.4.2-py36h3ef6317_1                   --> 1.4.1-py36_0               conda-forge
partd:                              0.3.8-py36hc8e763b_0                   --> 0.3.8-py36_0               conda-forge
path.py:                            10.3.1-py36h3dd8b46_0                  --> 10.3.1-py36_0              conda-forge
pathlib2:                           2.3.0-py36h7bfb78b_0                   --> 2.3.0-py36_0               conda-forge
pickleshare:                        0.7.4-py36h9de030f_0                   --> 0.7.4-py36_0               conda-forge
pip:                                9.0.1-py36hadba87b_3                   --> 9.0.1-py36_1               conda-forge
pkginfo:                            1.4.1-py36hb0f9cfa_1                   --> 1.4.1-py36_0               conda-forge
ply:                                3.10-py36h1211beb_0                    --> 3.10-py36_0                conda-forge
progress:                           1.3-py36hbeca8d3_0                     --> 1.3-py36_0                 conda-forge
prompt_toolkit:                     1.0.15-py36h60b8f86_0                  --> 1.0.15-py36_0              conda-forge
psutil:                             5.4.0-py36h4e662fb_0                   --> 5.4.0-py36_0               conda-forge
pycodestyle:                        2.3.1-py36h7cc55cd_0                   --> 2.3.1-py36_0               conda-forge
pycparser:                          2.18-py36hd053e01_1                    --> 2.18-py36_0                conda-forge
pycrypto:                           2.6.1-py36he68e6e2_1                   --> 2.6.1-py36_1               conda-forge
pyflakes:                           1.6.0-py36h0b975d6_0                   --> 1.6.0-py36_0               conda-forge
pygments:                           2.2.0-py36hb010967_0                   --> 2.2.0-py36_0               conda-forge
pyodbc:                             4.0.17-py36h0006bc2_0                  --> 4.0.17-py36_0              conda-forge
pyopenssl:                          17.2.0-py36h15ca2fc_0                  --> 17.2.0-py36_0              conda-forge
pyparsing:                          2.2.0-py36h785a196_1                   --> 2.2.0-py36_0               conda-forge
pyqt:                               5.6.0-py36hb5ed885_5                   --> 5.6.0-py36_4               conda-forge
python-dateutil:                    2.6.1-py36h509ddcb_1                   --> 2.6.1-py36_0               conda-forge
pywin32:                            221-py36h9c10281_0                     --> 221-py36_0                 conda-forge
pyyaml:                             3.12-py36h1d1928f_1                    --> 3.12-py36_1                conda-forge
qt:                                 5.6.2-vc14h6f8c307_12                  --> 5.6.2-vc14_1               conda-forge [vc14]
qtawesome:                          0.4.4-py36h5aa48f6_0                   --> 0.4.4-py36_0               conda-forge
qtconsole:                          4.3.1-py36h99a29a9_0                   --> 4.3.1-py36_0               conda-forge
qtpy:                               1.3.1-py36hb8717c5_0                   --> 1.3.1-py36_0               conda-forge
requests:                           2.18.4-py36h4371aae_1                  --> 2.18.4-py36_1              conda-forge
ruamel_yaml:                        0.11.14-py36h9b16331_2                 --> 0.11.14-py36_0             conda-forge
simplegeneric:                      0.8.1-py36heab741f_0                   --> 0.8.1-py36_0               conda-forge
singledispatch:                     3.4.0.3-py36h17d0c80_0                 --> 3.4.0.3-py36_0             conda-forge
sip:                                4.18.1-py36h9c25514_2                  --> 4.18-py36_1                conda-forge
six:                                1.11.0-py36h4db2310_1                  --> 1.11.0-py36_1              conda-forge
snowballstemmer:                    1.2.1-py36h763602f_0                   --> 1.2.1-py36_0               conda-forge
sortedcollections:                  0.5.3-py36hbefa0ab_0                   --> 0.5.3-py36_0               conda-forge
sortedcontainers:                   1.5.7-py36ha90ac20_0                   --> 1.5.7-py36_0               conda-forge
sphinxcontrib-websupport:           1.0.1-py36hb5e5916_1                   --> 1.0.1-py36_0               conda-forge
statsmodels:                        0.8.0-py36h6189b4c_0                   --> 0.8.0-py36_0               conda-forge
sympy:                              1.1.1-py36h96708e0_0                   --> 1.1.1-py36_0               conda-forge
tblib:                              1.3.2-py36h30f5020_0                   --> 1.3.2-py36_0               conda-forge
testpath:                           0.3.1-py36h2698cfe_0                   --> 0.3.1-py36_0               conda-forge
tk:                                 8.6.7-vc14hb68737d_1                   --> 8.6.7-vc14_0               conda-forge [vc14]
traitlets:                          4.3.2-py36h096827d_0                   --> 4.3.2-py36_0               conda-forge
typing:                             3.6.2-py36hb035bda_0                   --> 3.6.2-py36_0               conda-forge
unicodecsv:                         0.14.1-py36h6450c06_0                  --> 0.14.1-py36_0              conda-forge
urllib3:                            1.22-py36h276f60a_0                    --> 1.22-py36_0                conda-forge
vc:                                 14-h2379b0c_2                          --> 14-0                       conda-forge
wcwidth:                            0.1.7-py36h3d5aa90_0                   --> 0.1.7-py36_0               conda-forge
webencodings:                       0.5.1-py36h67c50ae_1                   --> 0.5-py36_0                 conda-forge
win_inet_pton:                      1.0.1-py36he67d7fd_1                   --> 1.0.1-py36_1               conda-forge
win_unicode_console:                0.5-py36hcdbd4b5_0                     --> 0.5-py36_0                 conda-forge
wincertstore:                       0.2-py36h7fe50ca_0                     --> 0.2-py36_0                 conda-forge
wrapt:                              1.10.11-py36he5f5981_0                 --> 1.10.11-py36_0             conda-forge
xlsxwriter:                         1.0.2-py36hf723b7d_0                   --> 1.0.2-py_0                 conda-forge
xlwt:                               1.3.0-py36h1a4751e_0                   --> 1.3.0-py36_0               conda-forge
yaml:                               0.1.7-vc14hb31d195_1                   --> 0.1.7-vc14_0               conda-forge [vc14]
zict:                               0.1.3-py36h2d8e73e_0                   --> 0.1.3-py_0                 conda-forge
zlib:                               1.2.11-vc14h1cdd9ab_1                  --> 1.2.11-vc14_0              conda-forge [vc14]
```

menuinst-1.4.8 100% |###############################| Time: 0:01:34 992.35  B/s
ca-certificate 100% |###############################| Time: 0:01:01   3.02 kB/s
intel-openmp-2 100% |###############################| Time: 0:01:05  21.61 kB/s
pandoc-2.1.1-0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:05:49  62.31 kB/s
pandoc-2.1.1-0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:06:05  59.53 kB/s
pandoc-2.1.1-0 100% |###############################| Time: 0:01:53 192.05 kB/s

CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/pandoc-2.1.1-0.tar.bz2
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/pandoc-2.1.1-0.tar.bz2
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/pandoc-2.1.1-0.tar.bz2
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

Comment: Did you try again later?

Comment: I did. But it kept showing the same error

Comment: It's a known bug [Conda Bug 6007](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6007) but unfortunately no fixes nor workarounds that have been discussed have worked for me. I've created 3 Conda environments today, without issue. When I tried creating the 4th, I too am seeing the CondaHTTPError: I cannot install nor updated any packages now. I don't know what to do.
The Anaconda developers have no response. The > conda clean --all
> > Blockquote mentioned elswhere in this thread, did not help me. I'm running Windows 7 Pro, 64-Bit.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this kind of error on two different occasions issuing the following command before updating:

```
conda clean --all
```

Which, according to conda's help docs, removes the following files:

> index cache, lock files, tarballs, unused cache
>                         packages, and source cache.

Regards.